# In JobService open SQLite database with Context

Tags: java, android, android-context, android-jobscheduler, jobservice

In my application I write jobs into a queue in a SQLite table.
With a JobService I would like to process this queue.

I'm currently struggling to access the database from inside the the JobService as I require the Context. Both getBaseContext() and getApplicationContext() leave me with

*Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference*

As I seem to gather from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService.html JobService seems to inherit from Context but it doesn't seem sufficient to just use **this** as Context.

I'm using a helper class extending SQLiteOpenHelper with the database.

Thank you for your time.

€: I was too hasty and tried to use **this** as context in my constructor. As soon as I moved my initialization code to a different part it works as intended.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would include the complete Java stack trace, plus your code that is referenced in that stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. It was a stupid mistake and I edited the solution into my question.